# Assembly build version at runtime in blazor wasm app

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

What is the best way to get build version number at runtime in web assembly client-side blazor app?
In server side version I was able to use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion.ToString();`

Combined with msbump package it was automatically generating new version for me with each new build. Is that possible to achieve at client side blazor too?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try using `GetExecutingAssembly()`.

Example:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
    GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().
    InformationalVersion;
```

The reason you can't use the entry assembly is I believe the entry assembly is not your actual assembly. So if you call out for executing assembly you are guaranteed to get your actual assembly.

Comment: This also works as a replacement for `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location).ProductVersion`.

Comment: What imports do we have to have in order to use this?

Comment: Does anyone know how to increment this number with each publish?

Comment: @Zapnologica. Have a look at [Blazor Tips-n-Tricks! Auto-Increment your Version tag with Powershell](http://lancelarsen.com/blazor-tips-n-tricks-auto-increment-your-version-tag-with-powershell/?msclkid=832716f8b44c11ecb98179f1802f66c6)

Comment: This also works with Blazor WASM

`Version version = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Version;`

Comment: @Zapnologica there is nuget package called msbump -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBump/
Here is readme how to configure it in your project:
https://github.com/BalassaMarton/MSBump
It works quite well.